# Updating a sql database using php

Tags: php, sql

What I am trying to do is updating multiple rows of mysql table having same id. I searched for many solutions but couldn't find appropriate one. I have a table that look likes below:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------------+----------+
| id | emp_id | job_id | basic_salary |   stat   |
+----+--------+--------+--------------+----------+
| 62 |    186 |     30 |         8400 | Active   |
| 64 |    110 |      8 |        12542 | Inactive |
| 65 |    110 |      5 |        12542 | Active   |
+----+--------+--------+--------------+----------+
```

So I want to update this table having `id = 64` and `emp_id = 110` as `Active` which should also update other rows with `emp_id 110` as `Inactive` if they are `Active` so that only one record with `emp id 110` remains `active` and rest `inactive`.

Will kindly appreciate the help.

Comment: One thing you could try is to store the active id in a boolean value (if you're altering the table scheme). Then you could check the active by searching employee ID and boolean value true.

Comment: thanks  Brandon White I will try your suggestion

Comment: try to use `CASE` for your condition

Comment: @R.Karki Can you clarify what you need there? With how you wrote it it sounds (to me at least) that you want to set specific emp_id + job_id combinations to active and AUTOMATICALLY set all other job_ids for that specific emp_id to inactive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
// first find all the records for the employee with status as Active and make them Inactive.
    $query1 = mysql_query("select * from table_employee where emp_id = 110 and status = 'Active' ");
    if($query1 && mysql_num_rows($query1) > 0)
    {
         while(mysql_fetch_array($query1))
         {
              mysql_query("update table_employee set status = 'Inactive' where emp_id = 110");
         }
    }

// then make the record Active that you you want to
$query2 = mysql_query("update table_employee set status = 'Active' where emp_id = 110 and id = 64");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Suyog. Your solution really helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Can try with these simple queries :-

```
UPDATE <table_name> SET `stat` = "Active" WHERE id = 64 AND emp_id = 110
```

and then :

```
UPDATE <table_name> SET `stat` = "Inactive" WHERE id <> 64 AND emp_id = 110
```

Comment: I think the purpose was for specific employee id's to act as individuals, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I think that the OP did mean it differently: He wants to set specific emps as active and then AUTOMATICALLY have the others set to inactive. But could be mistaken there (put up the question for clarification there in the comments section of the question itself).

Comment: Agreed, if the OP replies of what is needed, I would love to update the answer. But if this is not the case and it can be done with firing as much query he wants, this might be useful for R.Karki - maybe OP upvoted as it worked for him

Comment: Thanks for so much suggestions. To say it clearly for example if the table has more than one record of same employee id then only one record of that employee id can be active at a time while other rows of same employee id should remain inactive. So in above table if I update the record id=64 and emp_id=110 as active the other record id=65 and emp_id=110 should be inactive

Comment: is your problem solved by any of the answer posted or you're still looking for the fix ?

Comment: Thanks @JitendraPurohit your help and the following one by Suyog really helped.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is to store the active id in a boolean value (if you're altering the table scheme). Then you could check the active by searching employee ID and boolean value true.